# What happens when you call getChildren on it's own?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm relatively new to Java, especially Javafx and GUIs. I've been working on this code but I'm having some trouble understanding what THE VERY LAST LINE is doing. I understand the second last line is adding all the components to the container 'p', but what happens when you call getChildren() without a container before it. Anyways, any help is appreciated.

```
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class DVDButtonPane extends Pane {

    public DVDButtonPane(){
        Pane p = new Pane();

        Button add = new Button("Add");
        add.setPrefSize(95, 30);
        add.relocate(0, 0);
        add.setStyle("-fx-font: 12 arial; -fx-base: rgb(0,100,0); -fx-text-fill: rgb(255,255,255);");

        Button delete = new Button("Delete");
        delete.setPrefSize(90, 30);
        delete.relocate(100, 0);
        delete.setStyle("-fx-font: 12 arial; -fx-base: rgb(100,0,0); -fx-text-fill: rgb(255,255,255);");

        Button stats = new Button("Stats");
        stats.setPrefSize(90, 30);
        stats.relocate(210, 0);

        p.getChildren().addAll(add, delete, stats);
        getChildren().add(p);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`getChildren` is the same as calling `this.getChildren`. That line adds `p` to the children collection of the `DVDButtonPane`.

Answer (score 1):

its adding "p" to the DVDButtonPane. But if the DVDButtonPane itself is extending from Pane. You could have directly added the buttons to the DVDButtonPane